# Access predefined objects in header files

Tags: c++

I am working with an external library that will provide a class, say library_class_1, and it will take some inputs and return outputs as usual. I want to be able to access these outputs in a header file, in order to use this information in another class.
I am having trouble passing this information into my separate header files. I will post just an idea of the script as it is too big and contains a lot of other non-relevant information for this question.

#### "main.cpp"

```
#include header.h
int main {
...
  library_class_1 object_1;

  header object_2;
  object_2.DoSomething(...) // how to input object_1 correctly?
}
```

#### "header.h"

```
class header {

public:
header();
void DoSomething( ); // How can I pass object_1 in here?

}
```

#### "header.cpp"

```
#include header.h

header::header() {...}
header::DoSomething( ) // How can I pass object_1 in here?
{ 
// Here, I want to be able to access member functions of 
// object_1 
}
```

If I declare

#### "header.h"

```
header::DoSomething(library_class_1 & object_1);
```

#### "header.cpp"

```
void DoSomething(library_class_1 & object_1);
```

I get error:library_class_1 has not been declared (in "header.h")

I believe I have to declare this function somehow in "header.h", but I have not been able to do so. I tried defining

```
class library_class_1;
// or library_class_1 object_1;
```

in "header.h", without success.

Anyways, please don't mind formatting/implementation errors as I just wanted to give an idea of the question. I hope I explained correctly my question.

Comment: Please use the preview to verify that your post looks somewhat reasonable *before* posting. Corrected the most egregious errors. And proper formatting of the question is part of the minimal common courtesy expected in even not-so-polite company. You don't get excused just because you ask.

Comment: Your code-snippets are confusing. Normally when writing classes in C++, you have on <Classname>.cpp-file and one <Classname>.h[pp] file. Additionally, you need the header-file(s) of the library in question. You include the header-file of the library into the header-file of the Class and include the header-file of the class in the cpp-file of the class. You seem to be missing the header-file for the library you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a forward declaration of `library_class_1` in header.h before using it.

   ```
   class library_class_1;

   class header {
     public:
       header();
       void DoSomething(library_class_1 const&  object_1);
   }
   ```
2. Make sure to `#include` the .h file that defines `library_class_1` in header.cc.

   ```
   #include <librarry_class_1.h>

   void header::DoSomething(library_class_1 & object_1)
   {
       // Use object_1 ...
   }
   ```